# Specifying a list of items for the parameters with WorkItemStore.Query in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, wiql

I've got the following WIQL query for a TFS project:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Issue WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @Project "+
                "AND [Assigned To] IN (@AssignedTo)";

Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("Project","test");
parameters.Add("AssignedTo","'chris','tfsuser'");
WorkItemStore.Query(query, parameters);
```

This is being run via the .NET TFS API.

My problem is with the **AssignedTo** parameter. How is this meant to be specified? I've tried it as a `string[]`, `List<string>` as well as with and without quotes as above. Each one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just spent a few minutes looking at this.  I hope you get the answer, because I could definitely foresee running into this.  Worse comes to worse, you could just do string manipulation on your own and replace the @AssignedTo with the list of values of your choice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282712/how-to-use-limit-keyword-as-using-in-ms-sql-by-wiql-to-query-tfs-workitem

Could you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to do, but it doesn't look like it's possible. The query that you want is this:

```
WHERE [System.AssignedTo] in ('John Smith', 'Jane Citizen')
```

Which is semantically the same as this:

```
WHERE [System.AssignedTo] = 'John Smith' OR [System.AssignedTo] = 'Jane Citizen'
```

The only way I can work out how to achieve it in code is by specifying the identities as separate parameters:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs/"));
WorkItemStore wis = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

values.Add("parameter1", "John Smith");
values.Add("parameter2", "Jane Citizen");

Query query = new Query(wis, "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.AssignedTo] IN (@parameter1, @parameter2)", values);

WorkItemCollection workItems = wis.Query(query.QueryString);
WorkItem workItem = workItems[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigned To field is actually [System.AssignedTo].  I don't believe using the display name of the field will work.

Comment: I have tried both and neither work unfortunately. I think I'm going to have scrap the parameters and do some string concat